# Bootstrap Grid/CSS: Wrap longer column around shorter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

In the two columns to the farthest right, I would like to wrap the left column around the right column if it is longer. This means the child divs of the left column should extend their width. I've tried floating the right column, but that did not work.

I am using the bootstrap grid system for the columns. Essentially what I have is

```
<div class="col-xs-6" >
<div class="col-lg-6 left-column">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 right-column">
</div>
</div>
```

If you would like to play around with the actual webpage yourself please see here: mighty-cliffs-9655.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create multiple wrappers.

give this a try i have just given the classes the css values replace these with the bootstrap grid.

%"variable"% = placeholder (I assume you're working in a CMS)

You just need to set the height of each item to 100% or auto and this should do the job!

```
<div class="wrapper width100% floatleft">
<div class="left width50% floatLeft">
    <div class="today floatLeft">%today%</div>
    <div class="tomorrow floatRight">%tomorrow%</div>
</div>
<div class="right width50% floatRight">
    <div class="sunday floatLeft">%sunday%</div>
    <div class="sidebar floatRight">%sidebar%</div>
</div>  
</div>
```